# Change visibility of div inside a page

Tags: asp.net

I am having task to hide the visibility of a div inside a page from a user control.
I am using VS2010 and c#

The problem is in detail
I have a page contains sever panels and one is documentation header with div contains a paper clip image.inside the panel contains user control that shows the documents name in a grid.
What i am trying to do is from the usercontrol if the grid is empty i am going to hide the div from usercontrol.

```
if (files.Count > 0)
           {
              this.Page.FindControl("divPaperClip").Visible = true;
           }
           else
               this.Page.FindControl("divPaperClip").Visible = false;
```

I tried this but it throws error.

and the aspx code is below in inside a page

```
<label class="lblStandard" style="float: left; position: relative; top: -2px;padding-left:1em; text-align:left">
                        Documentation</label>
                        <div runat="server" id="divPaperClip"><img style="float: left; padding-top: 3px;" src="Images/paperClip.png"
                        alt="Paper Clip" /></div>
```

Comment: What is the full exception message?

Comment: Is it a div with runat=server applied, or an ASP.NET Panel control? If it's a div you'd need to apply a style, not set the visible attrbute.

Comment: <label class="lblStandard" style="float: left; position: relative; top: -2px;padding-left:1em; text-align:left">
                            Documentation</label>
                            <div runat="server" id="divPaperClip"><img style="float: left; padding-top: 3px;" src="Images/paperClip.png"
                            alt="Paper Clip" /></div>

Comment: exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: this.Parent.FindControl("divPaperClip").Visible = true; working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you should be able to do something like this..

```
//buttonclick or something
{
  divPaperClip.Visible = false;
}
```

then make sure in your control you have runat="server"

Answer (score 0):

Thy this:

```
divPaperClip.Visible = files.Count > 0 ? true : false;
```